# Jaeger with a single remote agent

Tags: jaeger

- Would a single agent colocated with a single collector be possible in a Jaeger deployment?
- Would it be advisable?
- Is it possible to skip the agent altogether and submit spans directly to the collector over HTTP? (This is mentioned in the documentation but with no details of how this might be achieved.) How scalable would this be?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to bypass agent all together and send metrics directly to collector.

Just define variable JAEGER_ENDPOINT in your app running environment.

This behaviour is documented but buried down in the Jager git repo:

https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-java/blob/master/jaeger-core/README.md

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, it's possible. You can deploy these as you would any typical service.
- This is situation dependent. It's generally preferrable to extract metrics/logging to their own instances as the performance requirements are potentially different from your applications.
- This is possible to achieve if you configure your instrumentation to communicate directly to the collectors. The collector can receive spans via HTTP on port 14268 (https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.6/deployment).

Scalabilty is dependent on sampling frequency and volumes. The agent supports adaptive sampling which is a feedback loop from the collector to your instrumented app.

You can statically define this up front in your instrumentation but you lose the adaptive features.

Answer (score 0):

> Would a single agent colocated with a single collector be possible in a Jaeger deployment?

It's possible, and that's how the ["all-in-one"](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.8/getting-started/#all-in-one) image works.

> Would it be advisable?

Depends on your architecture. If you don't expect your Jaeger infra to grow, using the all-in-one is easier from the maintenance perspective. If you need your Jaeger infra to be highly available, then you probably want to place your agents closer to your instrumented applications than to your collector and scale the collectors separately.

More about the Jaeger Agent is discussed in the following blog posts:

[Running Jaeger Agent on bare metal](https://medium.com/jaegertracing/running-jaeger-agent-on-bare-metal-d1fc47d31fab)
[Deployment strategies for the Jaeger Agent](https://medium.com/jaegertracing/deployment-strategies-for-the-jaeger-agent-1d6f91796d09)

> Is it possible to skip the agent altogether and submit spans directly to the collector over HTTP?

For some clients (Java, NodeJS and C#), yes. Look for the [`JAEGER_ENDPOINT` option](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.8/client-features/).